# Images are loading in eclipse, but are not working in exported Jar

Tags: java, eclipse

Title says it all, when I compile in eclipse it works fine, when I Export to a Jar file, they don't show up.

If you need anymore of the code, I will provide.

```
Image sprite = new ImageIcon("Sprites/Characters/spikeEnemy.png").getImage();

sprite = (e) ? new ImageIcon("Sprites/enemyProjectile.png").getImage() : new ImageIcon("Sprites/projectile.png").getImage();
```

(e: true for enemy, false for ally) sprite is declared earlier as (private Image sprite)

Comment: Do you expect the images to live in the jar?  Are they in the jar?

Comment: @Talyor
They are in the src folder when I am exporting the file.

Comment: if you open up the jar are they inside?

Comment: I just used an online decompiler, and they are not. Am I putting the Sprites folder in the wrong spot?

They are in the src folder

Comment: FYI, jars are just zip files with internal folder structure conventions.  However you're building the jar is not including the image files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]you need to use getClassLoader:
put the picture inside the src forlder

```
Image sprite = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path));
```

-> src /icons/icon.png

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("icons/icon.png"));
```

this whay the image will be inside the executable jar

Comment: `try {
        sprite = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Sprites/Characters/Player1.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}`

Sorry about the formatting ^, it is being weird.

Error:
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)

Comment: is Sprites folder inside the src folder inside your java project?

Comment: I have tried with it inside src, and right outside of the src folder. (with bin and .settings)

Comment: NB: case sensitive watchout

Comment: create a package call it icons like i did put the picture inside it try to call like i did i always do that

Answer (score 0):

This is a build path issue.

Right click the project in eclipse -> add source folder. Place your images in there and update your references in your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I now got it to only work in JAR files, but it doesn't work in eclipse...

I accidently ran it like

```
sprite = new ImageIcon("Sprites/Characters/Player1.png").getImage();
```

And the sprites now show up in the jar, but there is no folder called "Sprites" anymore. So is it just a default thing you are suppose to put there?